# How to define a type of typescript with a variable number of keys?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have the following case I don't know exactly how to express in typescript:

```
{
  "things": {
    "a": 11,
    "b": 22,
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

Then I would like to define something like:

```
type Response<T> = { [_: string]: T }
```

So the type above represents any response with a key and a certain value of type T, but I will have many keys like stated in the json, "a" "b"... and I don't find the type for it.

Comment: Try this `interface IInnerObj { [key: string]: number} interface IouterObj { things: IInnerObj }`

Comment: if not necessary, keep your "things" object as  things: any

Comment: I think you might be looking for generics. [**TypeScript Generics**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

Comment: ... after doing some tries this one represented the JSON:
type Response<T> = { [key: string]: { [key: string]: T } }

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should work:

```
interface Response<T> {

    things: {
        [key: string]: T;
    };
}
```

If you have certain keys fixed like `a`, you can do:

```
interface Response<T, R> {

    things: {
        // fixed keys
        a: R;
        // some more fixed keys.

        [key: string]: T;
    };
}
```

Comment: This is also possible: type Response<T> = { [key: string]: { [key: string]: T } , the solution you present also solves the problem

Comment: Yes. Indeed. Just that is it a common practice to prefer interfaces over type aliases when defining the shape of an object. Type aliases are used to create aliases, union types, partials, etc.